# Where to store the connection string in an Azure Web App for blob storage

Tags: azure

https://azure.microsoft.com/sv-se/documentation/articles/storage-dotnet-how-to-use-blobs/

The article does not say where to store the connection string for a Azure Web App.

Does anyone know?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer further down the article :)

Configuring your connection string using .NET configuration

If you are writing an application that is not an Azure cloud service, (see previous section), it is recommended you use the .NET configuration system (e.g. web.config or app.config). This includes Azure Websites or Azure Virtual Machines, as well as applications designed to run outside of Azure. You store the connection string using the  element as follows.

Answer (score 1):

Azure Web Apps (websites) provide an `Application settings` configuration area that you can access to store these types of settings:

[image: App settings]

These settings may be in your web.config, as you already discovered. However, if you specify them in your `Application settings` for your Web App, the `web.config` values will be overridden by values found in `Application settings` (see [this article](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/windows-azure-web-sites-how-application-strings-and-connection-strings-work/) which mentions this specifically).

Comment: Marked my own as answer but this is good additional knowledge

Answer (score 0):

You usually store connection strings in:

App.config